# Auto Relacionamento

Tags: oracle, relacionamento

Tenho uma tabela de medicamentos.

Nela tenho:

- codigo do medicamento (PK)
- descricao
- codigo ans

Existe a possibilidade de termos mais de um codigo de medicamento para o mesmo código ans.

Preciso fazer uma consulta que traga todos os medicamentos que tem o codigo ans igual e o codigo do medicamento diferente.

Uso Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso específico não ficou claro se realmente se trata de auto relacionamento. Talvez você devesse alterar um pouco sua pergunta pra dar mais detalhes.

Mas, falando da sua consulta, tente usar `GROUP BY` com a clásula `HAVING`.

```
SELECT codigo_medicamento, codigo_ans
  FROM medicamentos
 GROUP BY codigo_ans HAVING COUNT(codigo_medicamento) > 1
```

Contamos quantos `codigo_medicamento` **diferentes** temos para cada `codigo_ans` e filtramos apenas aqueles em que a **contagem é maior do que 1**.

Não tenho como testar com *ORACLE*, mas tente e retorne em caso de erro.